# Generating vertical sections in 3D models in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, netcdf, kriging, 3d-model

I have a model in NetCDF from EBK 3D in ArcGIS Pro and I need to take a vertical section, but ArcGIS only provides horizontal sections, has anyone faced this issue and know how to get vertical sections?

[image]

Comment: Not done it myself, but [voxels](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/voxel-layer-sections.htm) may be your solution?

Comment: @Hornbydd Thank you! It works perfectly!